# API call - What happen to file?

Tags: python, rest, api, with-statement

I am in this kind of situation: I have a file on a server and I use a script to make a REST API call. This call is gonna open the file, read it and search inside the value I sent; in the end, the file is being closed (usual `with open as` synthax).

Now, inside the file there is a timestamp which I use to say to the script: if value of `time.now - timestamp` is over 30 minutes, then update the file. Updating consist in download some files, merge them and finally create my new main file.

My question is: what happens if, considering that more than 30 minutes passed, I do 2 (or more) calls at the same time ?

I premise that for now no controls are implemented.

What I expect is that the "first" call will lock the file to update it, but the "second" ? I will have any kind of error ?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about how to handle race-conditions???

Comment: yes, thanks. I didn't knew there is a term for that. Im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

No error but ultimately the file will be overwritten by the last call. There will be no lock. You'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Last call will not throw any error (aka will do normal workflow) if is being executed AFTER the first. But what if the second call is DURING the first ?

Comment: Just try it. You can se `time.sleep()` to delay the first call. Even if its during, whichever call writes the file later, will overwrite.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say that, unless 30 minutes passed, any call I made will not trigger the update. By that, there is any tool I can use to achieve this ?

Comment: You can keep a shared lock (just a key in Redis maybe) and check that before triggering the update.